# Default checked checkbox in DataTables Javascript

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have the following datatable and it works perfectly but is it possible to have the default for the checkbox set to selected?

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        data         : dataSet.data,
        paging       : false,
        ordering     : false,
        searching    : false,
        destroy      : true,
        select       : { style:    'os', 
                         selector: 'td:first-child'},

        columnDefs   : [ { orderable: false,
                           className: 'select-checkbox',
                           targets:   0,
                           }
        ],

        columns      : [ { data: "selected" },
                         { data: "Column1", title: "Column1" },
                         { data: "Column2", title: "Column2" },
        ]   
    });
```

Comment: why dont you iterate through dataSet.data and update the "selected" property values to true before datatables call?

Answer (score 0):

doing a 'render' of 'NOT selected' should work.....

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    data         : dataSet.data,
    paging       : false,
    ordering     : false,
    searching    : false,
    destroy      : true,
    select       : { style:    'os', 
                     selector: 'td:first-child'},

    columnDefs   : [ { orderable: false,
                       className: 'select-checkbox',
                       targets:   0,
                       render: function (data, type, row){
                           return !data;
                       }
                     }
    ],

    columns      : [ { data: "selected" },
                     { data: "Column1", title: "Column1" },
                     { data: "Column2", title: "Column2" },
    ]   
});
```